# How to externalize configuration without using spring cloud config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have a microservice application which has a REST controller and uses an ObjectMapper - trip-definition-service.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TripDefintionService extends TripCommonApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 SpringApplication.run(args, TripDefinitionService.class);
}
```

Now I want another microservice application to create a bean for that same ObjectMapper - trip-common-service.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public abstract class TripCommonApplication { }
```

As of now I have build trip-common-service and have kept a jar as a dependency on trip-definition-service.

Now I have a configuration created on trip-common for ObjectMapper as follows -

```
@Configuration
@Qualifier("standardObjectMapper")
public ObjectMapper getMapper() {
   return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

And I am using a the ObjectMapper which was created in trip-common in my trip-definition-service.

```
@Service
public class Service {

 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("standardObjectMapper")
 private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

 public void doSomething() {
      objectMapper.readValue(......);
 }
```

Now when I start my trip-definition-service, it says its not able to find an `ObjectMapper` bean of type `standardObjectMapper`.

Need some help/suggestions on this and how to get this done.

Comment: What is the package structure?  Perhaps `TripDefintionService`'s @SpringBootApplication needs to have `TripCommonApplication`'s package added as a base package to scan.

Comment: First of all, why you need ObjectMapper as a bean ? why cant just use ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper() or how about moving it to a static utility class ?

Comment: @Barath I have different objectMapper properties set for other microservices as well.

Comment: @AndrewS trip-definition and trip-common are two seperate microservice applications and have their own respective packages